# How can I find my cats' secret peeing spot?

Tags: cats, urination

To sum it up succinctly, I have three cats and when I come home, I notice my house smells of cat urine. I could probably eliminate the odour if I could just figure out where it is emanating from specifically. Apparently, one (and I have a pretty good idea which one it is) of my cats is choosing to pee in some secret spot.

Any ideas on how I might find where that spot or spots are at?

It's kind of hard, because the whole living/dining/kitchen area just sort of reeks of it.

Comment: You could secretly follow them on days when you are completely at home. Keep an eye on them when they try to sneak off

Comment: As you did not mention multiple litter boxes, you may also want to see this related question [In a multiple cat home, how many litter boxes should you have?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/24063/13)

Comment: can't you follow the smell?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cat urine glows under UV light, so you can find the exact spot with a UV flashlight shining at a wavelength of 365-385 nm (that's the scientific specification of where on the *ultraviolet* spectrum the light exactly is).

> A lower rating won’t be strong enough to light up the cat urine, and a higher rating is too similar to natural light to have an effect.

- You can find these lights online or at a local home improvement store.
- You can also find UV lights with fluorescent bulbs. As long as it’s rated between 365-385 nm, this will work as well, although the LED lights tend to be stronger.

Wait until it's completely dark outside, then turn off any lights in the room but the UV light. The glow is too weak to be seen when other light sources illuminate the room.

Be aware that there are many other substances that glow under UV light. Urine glows yellow or neon green and you still have to smell the stain to be sure it's urine.

See detailed instructions and more information in this [WikiHow article](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-Cat-Urine-With-a-UV-Light).

Comment: if you look for black light on internet you will find it,you will need one that is 5-10watts urine is one of the body fluids you can find :)